# How can I specify the language when using shopify-api-node to list products from a site with multiple languages

Tags: shopify, shopify-api-node

I am trying to access the English product translations from a site that defaults to Italian.

/products/ = Italian 
/en/products = English 
/es/products/ = Spanish

The access token is for the Admin API and has access to the scopes `read_products` and `read_product_listings`

```js
const ShopifyAPI = require('shopify-api-node');
const shopify = new ShopifyAPI({shopName, apiVersion, accessToken});

const data = await shopify.product.list()
```

### Solution: Use GraphQL

```js
const query = `{
  products(first:10,reverse:true){edges{node{
    id 
    translations(locale:"en"){key locale value}
  }}}
}`

const data = await shopify.graphql(query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shopify GraphQL API offers up an endpoint you can use where you provide the resource ID you are interested in, ie) a product ID, and you can get back the translations assigned to it. I would therefore read the docs on translations and move on from there.